# cmake does not find openssl library on mac os x (despite manually adding )

Tags: c++, cmake, openssl

I'm trying to compile https://github.com/dmikushin/binance-cxx-api on osx 10.13.6 
(since code is written for linux i had to adjust things a little)

I get following errors (which are openssl related as far as i see):

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_EVP_sha256", referenced from:
      binance::hmac_sha256(char const*, char const*) in binance_utils.cpp.o
  "_HMAC", referenced from:
      binance::hmac_sha256(char const*, char const*) in binance_utils.cpp.o
  "_SHA256_Final", referenced from:
      binance::sha256(char const*) in binance_utils.cpp.o
  "_SHA256_Init", referenced from:
      binance::sha256(char const*) in binance_utils.cpp.o
  "_SHA256_Update", referenced from:
      binance::sha256(char const*) in binance_utils.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

The project is cmake based and does not find or link against openssl (installed with homebrew)

I added include and lib dirs directly in the cmake GUI -> compiler, linker flag
(took the include dir, still gave me the errors)

Also applied several combinations of below and alike => didn't make the error go away

```
cmake -DOPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2d_1/include  -DOPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2d_1/lib/libcrypto.dylib -DOPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2d_1/lib/libssl.dylib
```

googling did not bring up new ideas (most of these errors seem to be fixed by the cmake -DOPENSSL.. option)

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider editing the cmake project ?

Adding the following lines in the `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenSSL)
if(${OpenSSL_FOUND})
  INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()
```

And editing the following line to link to OpenSSL

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} jsoncpp curl websockets ssl crypto)
```